# Objects, boolean logic, and boxing nil in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I would like to return an NSDictionary which might contain an NSError value for one key, and if not, should contain a null value. I know that I cannot actually set a value to nil because it is not an object, but why can I not use the || operator to return NSNull if my NSError is nil?

```
if (requestError || ![matches count]) {
    return @{@"success": @NO,
             @"error": requestError || [NSNull null],
             @"country": country};
}
```

The error I get is `Collection element of type 'int' is not an Objective-C object`. I understand that nil is an int value, but why does `nil || NSObject` not guarentee that an NSObject will be returned?

Comment: The syntax is wrong, it goes Condition? TrueResult : FalseResult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `||` operator returns a boolean, so `requestError || [NSNull null]` returns `YES` or `NO`. You could use the ternary operator instead:

```
@"error": requestError ? requestError : [NSNull null],
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew that was an alternative but I wanted to make sure I understood why. I am used to ruby where it is very convenient to use `||` to fault in objects.

Comment: You could simplify this too by doing @"error": (requestError ?: [NSNull null]),

Comment: @Christian That is interesting. Basically the equivalent of or-equals when used with assignment.